# How define a maxlenght in a element

Tags: javascript, html

If i have this snippet

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
```

and I want to define a maxlenght in the element, for when the sever return much characters, making something like this:

```
<p data-maxlenght="127">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua...</p>
```

how i do? Thnks in advance

Comment: can't you trim it on the serverside?

Comment: no =/ - I just work in the front end in this project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no max-length (length not lenght) on paragraph tags because they are not inputs. So you can either write a server side function that truncates the text to the desired length before returning it to the user (which would be the preferable route) or use a client side function in javascript/jquery to truncate it during or after loading it for example

```
var p = $('#myParagraph');
p.text(p.text().substring(0,127))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are dozens of good options out there ranging from CSS only solutions to JS empowered ones.  See this URL: http://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know in how search it